# bold links by matching current URL with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

Tags: php

I am trying to create bold links in a menu depending on which page the visitor is currently on. I managed to get it working with the following code, but the problem is that my code has the possibility of sub-menus under options, so links may be:

```
index.php?page=category
index.php?page=category&subcategory=something
index.php?page=category&subcategory=somethingelse
```

The subcategories are working fine, but the problem is, I have no way of matching "index.php?page=category" because then both subcategories "something" and "somethingelse" also go bold.

Is there any way to match the exact string of "page=category" but no further?

```
<?
$urlstring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if (preg_match ("/page=category/i", $urlstring)) {
echo "<b>";
}
?>
```

Comment: preg_match is over kill what's wrong with $_GET['page'] ??

Comment: You should provide more details about your page site structure. I guess you are reloading index.php every time a menu option is selected. Instead, I'd suggest you to keep the menu fixed and update an iFrame with the content of the selection. You wouldn't even need PHP to achieve both this effect and the bold effect.

Comment: You could check out [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).  That probably is able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah just use `$_GET['page']`

Also, you might want to apply a class with boldness to whatever element you're bolding rather than using `<b>` (you have more control over the style, you could even alter the color)

Cheers
-D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just the equals operator,

```
if ("page=category" == $url_string)
```

This is clearer, easier to read, and probably faster.

Having said that you can achieve the same result by modifying the regex slightly with markers that specify the beginning and end of the string, like this:

```
if (preg_match("/^page=category$/"', $url_string)
```

The dollar sign ensures the comparison is with a string that doesn't go any further (there is nothing past the "y" in "category.". The caret (^) does the same at the beginning of the string: it specifies that you are checking for a string that begins exactly with "page=cat..."

For more about this sort of regex usage: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html